# IMAP "Invalid Credentials" error via GMail XOAUTH

Tags: oauth, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am using Gmail IMAP API with (deprecated) OAuth 1.0 in my app.
I have actually hundreds of users using the same app and majority of them are using the services without an issue. However there are some accounts, constantly receives "Invalid Credentials" error while trying to connect.
The issue does not necessarily show up instantly, there are many cases that the problem arises after a while.
I strongly don't think it is not related to incorrect tokens, because tokens were regenerated several times. Also they share the same code base with other accounts, I guess it should be working for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be related to your users having too many open connections to Gmail - a maximum of ten is allowed before they start 
complaining.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97150

> Gmail currently has a limit of 10 simultaneous IMAP connections per
>   account.